# Usage of “net of”

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

everyone:

Do the following two sentences mean the same thing:

1. Your final take-home pay is $2,000 net of deduction of $150.
2. Your final take-home pay is $2,000, net of deduction of $150.

If not, which one means :

> the final take-home pay is $2,000.

And which one means that:

> the final take-home pay is $2,000 - $150

Which are the differences and why ?

Comment: Neither of these are idiomatic: "net of deduction of $150" is a phrase I've never seen before and it doesn't really make sense.  Are these sentences that you wrote yourself or did you find them somewhere?

Comment: This sounds like who you spoke with works in accounting and thinks everyone else is an accountant or is trying to deflect from the fact that your take-home pay is $1,850 instead of $2,000.  If this is for your work paycheck, ask this person "So, my take-home pay is $2,150?" and you should find out what this really means pretty quickly.

Comment: @LawrenceC Hi. This is not about my personal paycheck. The reason I am asking is I have seen contradictory usage in financial documents by supposedly native speakers and got quite confused. (I thought I knew the distinction before and wondered if they made a mistake.)

Comment: @CanadianYankee Hi, it is mostly used in accounting environment. People don’t use that often in normal conversations. Thx.

Comment: $2000.00 net of a $150.00 deduction. It's bad accounting English. net of means already deducted.

Comment: Note that nett with this meaning is normally spelt with two t's https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nett

Answer (score 1):

To me they would both mean the net pay is $2,000, and the gross pay is $2,150, though the phrasing is (perhaps deliberately) ambiguous. But to me, “$2,000(,) net (of)”, should always mean the $2,000 is the net amount after the deduction of $150. If they were using the term “net of” to mean they were going to take $150 off the $2,000, it’s incorrect English (whether the intent is to deceive or not).

In such a situation I’d almost always ask for clarity:

> What is my net pay?

> How much will actually be going into my bank account?

The term “take home pay” is a bit jargon-y and ambiguous, as it could mean net of something but not something else. Really it ought to mean “money in the bank”, but that’s not to say it would always be used that way.